# Store content offline until connection is established

Tags: javascript, php, html, ipad, offline

I am hoping for some help regarding an offline iPad application.

I have a form within the app that the user fills in, this form then links to a PHP script online. Obviously you can't run the script until you are on line. Is there any way at all of clicking the form submit button, if there is a connection it will connect to and run the PHP and if there is no connection it will automatically run the php in the background when a connection becomes available.

I have tried a number of different searches but have still been unsuccessful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most likely is possible to solve this problem with JavaScript, but that's not so straightforward. Since you are dealing with an iOS app where it is possible to check network connection status and listen for changes, you probably should create a service that receives the form data within your app. That service should store the data locally, find out when your target server is accessible and send it.

**UPDATE:**

If you are dealing with a web-app, the way to go for it still to implement a service in JavaScript that uses timed events (i.e. `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`) to check connection status. Upon submitting the form, prevent the default behaviour so the form is not submitted traditionally. Instead, store the data locally in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` and when your service finds the target server available, read the locally stored data and send it via AJAX.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! - Sorry I failed to mention that this is a webapp and is completely wrote in HTML5. Does this affect anything? Thanks again!

Comment: Ahh - I understand. For this to work, would the app have to be running, or would this run in the background?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how iOS handles a long running JavaScript in a WebView while the app is in background.

Comment: Okay no worries - Thank you very much for your help. Definitely a starting point for me!